# Specific files to include in gh-pages

Tags: git, github, configuration, github-pages

*Scenario: As the project currently exists, `master` and `gh-pages` are completely separate (`gh-pages` started as an orphan, doesn't share any code with `master`). The `gh-pages` branch has grown to include javascript code to run a client-side simulation.*

---

At this point, it makes sense to move the simulation code to `master` (it's now a feature of the project, unit testing, central location, etc).

How could I automatically push **certain files** from `master` to **specified locations** in `gh-pages`?

Or, more generally, how would you manage this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Sharing files across branches in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6230903/6309)", you could consider isolate that set of javascript code (with its unit testing) in its own git repo.

That would allow you to reference that repo both in the `master` branch and in the `gh-branch` of your main repo as:

- either a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21072554/6309)),
- or a [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) ([illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309), [quick tutorial here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/))

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]