# How to use files from another git remote repo without including it in my repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo locally. I want to use some files from other remote repos but I don't want to manually copy the files on to my repo locally or check it into my own repo. Is there any way I can just clone those files but they'll still be managed by the other repos and I can call git pull to pull any updates to only those files?

The idea is similar to a package manager but instead of with packages it's with git repo files. If I can't do this with files, what's the solution to  manage dependent github repos.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Git has a concept of [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) which might suit you:

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use
>   another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third
>   party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in
>   multiple parent projects.
>
> Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to
>   keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository.

AFAIK it is not possible to add a single file from other repository - you'll have to checkout the whole repo. Here're similar questions on checking out a single file:

- [Single file as Git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170930/single-file-as-git-submodule)
- [Linking a single file from another git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597748/linking-a-single-file-from-another-git-repository)

Comment: as a rule of the thumb avoid submodules like the plague. Is there anything stopping you from just checking out the remote repos locally?