# Share individual source files between Git repositories (coming from VSS 2005)

Tags: git, share

The company I work for currently uses SourceSafe 2005 and have agreed to move over to Git as our platform for source control. Currently within SourceSafe we use a lot of shared files, e.g.

```
--Repo 1
TestDlg.cpp
TestDlg.h
SharedUser.h (shared)
OtherExample.h

--Repo 2
TestOther.cpp
TestOther.h
SharedUser.h (shared)
OtherFile.h
```

In this example SharedUser.h is a shared file (from its own separate repo), so when it gets updated from its own project, these files stay up to date.

Coming from VSS, the company is insistent that if we move to Git, this should happen in the same way as it's used a lot within VSS for us currently.

After searching around I saw an answer regarding submodules, I'm wondering if this is the only option for something like this? I have not researched a lot into it yet, but had a quick glance over previous questions which do not seem to match our particular issue.

I'm hoping there is a similar way to how VSS manages this currently, although I'm not expecting something as easy - in VSS currently you can just drag the file from the original folder into another to share it.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so I can read up more about it and not go down the wrong path. Thank you in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single file as Git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170930/single-file-as-git-submodule)

Comment: Your options are: 1. git submodules, 2. git subtree, 3.versionning/publishing and using a packages or 4. everything in a monorepo. Everyones have advantages and inconvenients.

Comment: @Philippe - Thanks for the clarification, there is currently a lot of separate modules 50-100+ so I really do not want to go down the monorepo route. It just would have been nice for an easier way (like VSS' drag-and-drop) even with a client. I'll look into the other suggestions though.